# Drive apprear had random pariotions appear duplicating another drive after reinstalling windows

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, samsung-ssd

So I had 2x1TB SSD's and 1HD. One has windows on it and 2 others have encrypted partitions.

I just reinstalled windows 10. Afterwards, I found that my MBR and system partitions were on the second drive meaning windows spanned both drives during installation creating system partitions on a separate HD and could no longer boot if the other drive was unplugged.

So I unplugged all other drives and reinstalled windows again to ensure it only uses the one drive instead of creating this idiotic dependency on the other drive to function.

When I get back into windows I do all the updates, shut down, plug the other drive back and boot up once more.

In explorer and both the 1TB SSD's appear the same size partition. WTF. I go inside and they appear to have identical windows files. WTF!!!

The non-windows had an 800ish GB partition that was BitLocker encrypted and now it appears to be identical to the windows drive.

I open disk manager and the non-windows SSD seems to have almost copied the sizes of the partitions from the windows drive give or take.
[image]

DISK 2 =  windows SSD with space set aside during installation for Linux.

DISK 0 = The other SSD that had previously had 0 unallocated space. It used to have one big partition that was encrypted with Bitlocker and some tiny system partitions.

Any ideas about what could have happened?

PS - I'm not overly concerned if I've lost the data so I tried just deleting the partition and now I am left with two Unallocated spaces that won't join together for some reason and I cant use the full space of the drive.

[image]

EDI: I tried [another tool](https://www.partitionwizard.com/partitionmagic/portable-partition-magic.html) and appears there was a 16MB partition between the unallocated spaces that windows would not display.

[image]

I still have no idea how this could happen as the drive never had these partitions before it had a totally different set of portions.

I know they are not identical but it does seem rather odd that the two partitions it ended up with are around the same size as the main partition and free space don't thee windows drive.

Also cant explain how the drive seemed to have identical files as the windows drive when it never had windows on it. Its like the Samsung SSD was a symbolic link to the WD SSD.

Guessing nobody has any answer for this weird behaviour.

Comment: I would try a third-party disk management software of your choice and attempt to resolve this issue, I would also, perform a reboot. Nothing was copied, those disks, are clearly different sizes.  What might solve the problem is to create a partition for each unallocated space and assign a drive letter then delete both of them.

Comment: Creating and deleting resulted in two unallocated spaces again. Any free tools you recommend?

Comment: Pick one anyone whatever you want to use.  I am not going to suggest any specific tool for the job for obvious reasons.

Comment: If something strange happened to the disk, and if there is no data to save, just format the disk. I would suggest slow format (not quick) to renew all magnetic signatures (although slow).